# Flash CS3: Controlling a Movieclip with a button in Flash Actionscript 2

Tags: flash, button, movieclip, actionscript-2

I am trying to controll my movieclip with my buttons in Actionscript 2.
I have a loop in my movieclip, it goes frame 1-20 over and over again.  I want the button to move it to frame 21 and play it onwards from there. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buttoninstancename.onRelease = function()
{
movieclipinstancename.gotoAndPlay(21);
}
```

Comment: Yes i just figured this out after i posted :)
to others: give the movieclip a instance name, this i forgot and i instead wrote in the object name. Thanks alot digitalpencil!